# Does C omit the placement of the null character in a string constant if i explicitly place it for myself, or will it still add it?

Tags: c, string

Suppose you have this code:

```
char word[] = "Hello!\0"
```

Will the `word` array have one or two terminating null characters?

Comment: You could easily check this with `sizeof`.

Comment: @juanchopanza never let an obvious and simple test get in the way of an SO post:(

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6

Comment: @juanchopanza: It could still be implementation-specific left to the compiler. But reading the standard (aka "RTFM") as always helps.

Answer (score 5):

The string literal always appends a nul (`'\0'`) byte unless you specified the size of the array, so you will have two nul bytes in the string `"Hello!\0"`. If you wrote `char word[7] = "Hello!\0"` you would only have one nul byte in the array, since the size is now restricted to seven characters.

Comment: The one exception is in C (but not C++) if you give the exact size of the array to match:  `char word[7] = "Hello!\0";`

Comment: There are non "NULL" bytes. Please don't use the name of the `NULL` macro for integers. It is a _null **pointer** constant_. A null character is either just the integer constant `0` or `NUL` resp. `nul` (the latter is less prone to be confused with `NULL`).

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 6 In translation phase 7, **a byte or code of value zero is appended
>   to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string
>   literal** or literals.78) The multibyte character sequence is then
>   used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the
>   array elements have type char, and are initialized with the individual
>   bytes of the multibyte character sequence....

And (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 14 An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
>   literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
>   Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the terminating
>   null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size**)
>   initialize the elements of the array.

You can check it yourself running the following code snippet

```
char word[] = "Hello!\0";
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( word ) );
```

The output will be equal to `8`.

Answer (score 0):

it will add a terminator automaticly however when you want to print the word or use any function that stop when it detict \0 it will stop there .

example : string x = "loop007" ; if you print it the result would be the same loop007

however string x = "loo\0p007" will only print "loo"  since the compiler has found the terminator even though it is not the right on .

long story short , yes it adds it eventhough you have assigned one allready .

Answer (score 0):

> Will the `word` array have one or two terminating null characters?

```
char word[] = "Hello!\0"
```

The *array* will have 2 <strike>terminating</strike> null characters and a size of 8.
The *string* located at the start of `word[]` will have 1 *terminating* null character.  The `'\0'` after the *string* is not part of that *string*.

---

In C, *string literals* may contain many `'\0'`s.  The size of the string literal includes the coded characters and an appended null character: `'\0'`,

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof("Hello!\0Hello!\0Hello!\0Hello!\0"));
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof("Hello!\0" "Hello!\0" "Hello!\0" "Hello!\0"));
// both output 4*7+1 = 29
```

When initializing an character array with an unspecified length, the array size matches the size of the *string literal*.

```
char word[] = "Hello!\0Hello!\0Hello!\0Hello!\0"
printf("%zu\n", sizeof word);
// output 4*7+1 = 29
```

When printing a *string* (note this is not the same as *string literal*), printing continues up to, but not including the first encountered `'\0'`.

```
printf("[%s]\n", word);
// output [Hello!]
```

---

Pedantic detail:  `char word[] = "Hello!\0"` contains a *string literal*, not *string consonant*.